# Getting error while trying to download logs for Azure Table Storage using AzCopy

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azcopy

[image]

I would like to download logs for Azure Table Storage for the past 3 days. I am trying to that using AzCopy. I tried different combinations of URL HTTP/https and patterns, but still, I am getting an error while downloading the logs.  Am I passing any incorrect parameters to AzCopy?

Comment: 2 things: 1) instead of pasting image, please paste the tas text (you can certainly remove sensitive information) and 2) can you check if $logs container exist in your storage account. From the error message, it seems the container doesn't exist.

Comment: How to check whether $logs container exists or not?

Comment: You can see it with Microsoft's Storage Explorer.

Comment: I don't see it in there. I can only see the $Metrics**** and my table.

Comment: Did you check under containers? If it is not there then it means you've not enabled logging on your storage account.

Comment: I inserted a few entities in my table consecutively. 3 got inserted perfectly well, but one was inserted after 4 hours. I am trying to find the root cause of this. It looks like I haven't enabled the logging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149247/discussion-between-sameer-and-gaurav-mantri).

Comment: Hi @Sameer, are you able to download the logs now?

Comment: @FredHan Yeah! I enabled storage analytics and now can download the logs. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **$logs** container will be automatically created when [Storage Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/about-storage-analytics-logging) is enabled for a storage account. If you can not find the $logs container, please make sure if you have enabled Storage Analytics.

I enabled Storage Analytics and I can [download Storage Logging log data using Azure Copy Tool (AzCopy)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/enabling-storage-logging-and-accessing-log-data#a-namedownloadingstoragelogginglogdataa-downloading-storage-logging-log-data) on my side.

[image]